# Subversion 1.6 directories' timestamp is not SVN's last modified timestamp, why?

Tags: svn, directory, timestamp

I am using Subversion 1.6.11 (on Unix) and am trying to use `svn export` to get the head of the SVN repository in order to later `rsync` with my webserver.
My problem is that all the exported directories have the current time (= when the `svn export` was performed) instead of the `last modified timestamp` of the SVN revision.
All the files on the other hand have the correct timestamp.

1. How can I get the `last modified timestamp` of my directories as well?
2. I read that Subversion 1.7 tweaked the way they handle versioning on directories, but would upgrading really help me in with this problem?

Comment: Are you using the `use-commit-times` setting in `~/.subversion/config`?

Comment: yes, I am. Although here it should not matter since `svn export` should always be using the last commit times..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Using mtime for dirs is correct behavior from OS side (mtime is time of last modification, yes? Last modification is time, when last file is written inside dir, yes? SVN just do nothing on top of OS I/O)
2. 1.7 changed only Working Copy storage (WC-NG: one .svn in the WC-root instead of *each subdir*), thus - you'll got nothing useful for you with changes

`svn ls -v REPO_PATH` or `svn ls -v -R REPO_PATH` in bad case will show you last commit time for dir, you have only touch exported tree

Comment: thanks for your quick answer :)  But how can I use `touch` to update the directories' mtime timestamps? Can I just grep the time portion out of `svn ls -v DIR`'s output and use it as a parameter for `touch`? Or is there an easier way?

Comment: @Pitt - somehow :-). I just see: we have needed data, we must only transform it in some way and pipe

Comment: I'll look into it. Cheers for you help!